# How to save an orchard form to a database

Tags: orchardcms

I'm creating a fairly complex orchard form and need the results saved to a sql server database. From what I understand, I should be creating a workflow activity and then on form submit, connecting to the database and saving the data through C#. Is this the correct approach?

I could also just create a module which is my custom form, and build the form myself, but would like to take advantage of orchards forms.

My question is
1. Am I approaching this correctly? or is there an easier way to do this.
2. I haven't been able to find any documentation on creating custom workflow activities. Is this even possible to do? Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, the custom forms module already saves the results, you don't have to do anything more.
2. Yes, you can create custom activities. Look at the code for the existing activities for examples.

Comment: I need it to save into a custom SQL database/schema so it saving inside Orchard isn't good enough. Other processes (outside of Orchard) will access and process this data.

Comment: Then why do you want to use custom forms? Looks like what you need to do is write a controller and view.